# Rules for using realtime database of firebase without using authentication?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am want to use use only realtime database of firebase database without using authentication so what rules i have to write ?

I am using following set of rules but after sometime app is not working so what kind of rules i have to use for realtime database without using authentication?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: The rules look fine for granting everyone in the world full read/write access to the database. So if you're still getting permission denied with these rules, the problem is likely elsewhere. It's more likely we can help if you edit your question to show the exact, complete error message you get, and the minimal code with which any of us can reproduce that error. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.